# A Double divided by zero is returning a Divide by Zero error

Tags: c#, .net, double, divide-by-zero

I am experiencing an unexpected behaviour and was hoping someone could help with some guidance as to what areas to focus an investigation on.

I have two methods, one essentially performs a divide by zero test on a double, the second calls an `extern` method for an unmanaged dll.

**Note:** In the .Net runtime, dividing a Double by Zero should return an Infinity value (amusingly of either positive or negative flavours).

Pseudocode for what I am doing looks something like this:

```
InfinityTest(); // Returns an Infinity value as expected
DllCall();
InfinityTest(); // Divide by zero error on second call.
```

The first call to `InfinityTest()` returns the value Infinity as expected. The second call to `InfinityTest()` throws a Divide by Zero exception that I didn't expect.

**Update**

The effective `InfinityTest()` code below. For brevity I've removed try/catch elements, etc. I do not have permission to go into details about the `DllCall()` pseudocode element, apologies.

```
private double InfinityTest()
{
    double a = 1.0;
    int b = 0;
    return a / b;
}
```

Comment: Ouch! It looks like the DLL call changes some FP flags and doesn't put them back. :(

Comment: it will come only if tried to divide a number by zero, a number cannot be divided by zero

Comment: could we get the code for both methods?  More importantly the `infinityTest();`

Comment: Can you post the code from inside the "InfinityTest();"? Can you tell us what the DllCall does? Are there any reference passed to the DllCall?

Comment: comment out the DllCall - does it still throw the exception?

Comment: Is the DLL by any chance written in Delphi? I ran into the same problem many years ago when I was working on the VBScript interpreter. VBScript assumes that floating point errors silently set error bits on the FP chip; Delphi assumes that floating point errors cause exceptions and will reset the behaviour of the chip to meet its expectations.

Comment: @Nighil - Normally yes, and if this was an int I'd be happy, however the .Net runtime supplies a value of Infinity when a Double is divided by zero. Or, at least, it should  :)

Comment: @joe_coolish and @Cos Callis - I'll update the question with some code shortly.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - Interesting, I'll check.

Comment: No, it's certainly something to do with the call. I'll update the question to make it clearer, thanks.

Comment: @Eric Lippert I never found out what the third party dll was written in for you I'm afraid, but I have added a comment to Gabe's answer to follow up with some more details confirming what the problem was.

Comment: I ran into this issue the other day, I changed from `QueryPerformanceCounter` to `QueryThreadCycleTime` in my .NET profiler and started getting weird DivideByZero exceptions in profiled app.

Comment: Comments like that by Nighil is why there should be a downvote button for comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since it sounds like your DLL is changing the FP status word on you, your only choice may be to change it back. I would suggest P/Invoke to [`_clearfp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49bs2z07.aspx) or [`_fpreset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfy34skx.aspx). Here are their P/Invoke signatures:

```
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    static extern UInt32 _clearfp();
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    static extern void _fpreset();
```

This may not reset things back to exactly the way they were, but hopefully it will be close enough.

Comment: This is working around the issue fine for now while we look into why/how the dll is altering the floating point flags, thank you very much!

Comment: The third party has confirmed that their dll was indeed changing the FP status word. After a review at their end this was found to not be needed and the dll has been updated to work without the FP status word change. Thanks for your help.